# Image interpolation implementation with C++

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv, stl, implementation

I have a question related to the implementation of image interpolation (bicubic and bilinear methods) with C++. My main concern is speed. Based on my understanding of the problem, in order to make the interpolation program fast and efficient, the following strategies can be adopted:

1. Fast image interpolation using Streaming SIMD Extensions (SSE)
2. Image interpretation with multi-thread or GPU
3. Fast image interpolation algorithms
4. C++ implementation tricks

Here, I am more interested in the last strategy. I set up a class for interpolation:

```
     /**
        * This class is used to perform interpretaion for a certain poin in 
        * the image grid.
        */
        class  Sampling
        {
        public:
            //   samples[0] *-------------* samples[1]
            //              --------------
            //              --------------
            //   samples[2] *-------------*samples[3]
            inline void sampling_linear(unsigned char *samples, unsigned char &res)
            {
                unsigned char res_temp[2];
                sampling_linear_1D(samples,res_temp[0]);
                sampling_linear_1D(samples+2,res_temp[1]);
                sampling_linear_1D(res_temp,res);
            }
        private:
            inline void sampling_linear_1D(unsigned char *samples, unsigned char &res)
            {
            }
        }
```

Here I only give an example for bilinear interpolation. In order to make the program run faster, the inline function is employed. My question is whether this implementation scheme is efficient. Additionally, during the interpretation procedure if I give the use the option of choosing between different interpolation methods. Then I have two choices:

1. Depending on the interpolation method, invoke the function the perform interpolation for the whole image.
2. For each output image pixel, first determine its position in the input image, and then according to the interpolation method setting, determine the interpolation function.

The first method means more codes in the program while the second one may lead to inefficiency. Then, how could I choose between these two schemes? Thanks!

Comment: Be aware that inlining is ultimately a compiler decision.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Fast image interpolation using Streaming SIMD Extensions (SSE)

This may not provide desired result, because I expect that your algorithm will be memory-bounded rather than FLOP/s bounded.

I mean - it definitely will be improvement, but not beneficial in compare to implementation cost.

And by the way, modern compilers can perform auto-vectorization (i.e. use of SSE and futher extensions): [GCC starting from 4.0](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/tree-ssa/vectorization.html), [MSVC starting from 2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh872235.aspx), [MSVC Auto-Vectorization video lectures](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/C9-Lectures-Jim-Radigan-Inside-Auto-Vectorization/Jim-Radigan-Inside-Auto-Vectorization-1-of-n).

> Image interpretation with multi-thread or GPU

Multi-thread version should give good effect, because it would allow you to exploit all available memory throughput.

If you do not plan to process data several times, or use it in some way on GPU, then GPGPU may not give desired result. Yes, it will produce result faster (mostly due to higher memory speed), but this effect will be crossed out by slow transfer between main RAM and GPU's RAM.

Just for example, approximate modern throughputs:

1. CPU RAM ~ 20GiB/s
2. GPU RAM ~ 150GiB/s
3. Transfering between CPU RAM <-> GPU RAM ~ 3-5 GiB/s

For single pass memory bounded algorithms, in most cases, third item makes usage of GPUs impractical (for such algoirthms).

> In order to make the program run faster, the inline function is employed

Class member functions are "inline" by default. Beaware, that main purpose of "inline" is not actually "inling", but helping to prevent [One Definition Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule) violation when your functions are defined in headers.

There are compiler-dependent "forceinline" features, for instance MSVC has [__forceinline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z8y1yy88%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). Or abstracted from compiler ifdef'ed BOOST_FORCEINLINE macro.

Anyway, trust your compiler unless you don't prove otherwise (with help of assembler for example). Most important fact, is that compiler should see functions defenitions - then it can decide itself to inline, even if function is not inline itself.

> My question is whether this implementation scheme is efficient.

As I understand, as pre-step, you gather samples into 2x2 matrix. I think it may be better to pass directly two pointers to arrays of two elements within image directly, or one pointer + width size (to calc second pointer automaticly). However, it is not a big issue, most likely your temporary 2x2 matrix will be optimized away.

---

What is really important - is how you traverse your image.

Let's say for given x and y, index is calculated as:

```
i=width*y+x;
```

Then your traversal loop should be:

```
for(int y=/*...*/)
    for(int x=/*...*/)
    {
        // loop body
    }
```

Because, if you would chose another order (x first, then y) - it will be not cache-friendly, and as the result performance drop can be up to 64x (depending on your pixel size). You may check it just for your interest.

> The first method means more codes in the program while the second one may lead to inefficiency. Then, how could I choose between these two schemes? Thanks!

In this case, you can use compile-time polymorphism to reduce code amount in first version. For instance, based on templates.

Just look at [std::accumulate](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/accumulate.html) - it can be written once, and then it will work on different types of iterators, different binary operations (functions or functors), without imply any runtime penalty due to it's polymorphism.

[Alexander Stepanov says](http://www.stepanovpapers.com/BYTE_com.htm):

> For many years, I tried to achieve relative efficiency in more advanced languages (e.g., Ada and Scheme) but failed. My generic versions of even simple algorithms were not able to compete with built-in primitives. But in C++ I was finally able to not only accomplish relative efficiency but come very close to the more ambitious goal of absolute efficiency. To verify this, I spent countless hours looking at the assembly code generated by different compilers on different architectures.

---

Check [Boost's Generic Image Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/gil/doc/index.html) - it has good tutorial, and there is [video presentation](http://stlab.adobe.com/gil/presentation/index.htm) from author.